# OpenCV - Gray image to color does not work

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying this snippet of code:

```
img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(RUTA_IMAGEN, 'probetas2small.jpg'),0)
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(RUTA_IMAGEN, 'processed1.jpg'), img);
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(RUTA_IMAGEN, 'processed2.jpg'), cimg);
```

The initial image 'probetas2small.jpg' is in color.
Image 'processed1.jpg' is in gray and 'processed2.jpg' too...

How can I convert the initial processed image to color again?

(Sorry for my english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.When you convert from color to gray, you **lose information**, so the operation the other way around is not possible.

Converting color to gray (which is what you're doing in the first line by using imread with flag zero at the end) is doing like the following : for each pixel which is [b,g,r] in `img`, its value will be only one number, equal to 0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b. You lose the individual values of b, g and r.
So converting back to a (visually) colored image (what you try to do `cv2.cvtColor()`) is not possible. It's as if I give you a number (say 43) and ask you "which 3 numbers did I compute the mean of in order to obtain 43 ?". You can't answer this, and neither can `cv2.cvtColor()`. What this function does is simply yield a 3 channel image, but where each channel has the same value, giving a *structurally* color image, but a *visually* grayscale one.

(Thanks Dan in the comments for the correct formula RGB>Gray)

Comment: The gray value won't be "something like the mean", it will be `0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B` -- see [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I wasn't sure. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you load `probetas2small.jpg` into `img`, you already convert it to gray. Instead of

```
img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(RUTA_IMAGEN, 'probetas2small.jpg'),0)
```

where `0` denotes "read as gray", you should do

```
img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(RUTA_IMAGEN, 'probetas2small.jpg'))
```